# Redis store design for traditional "select * from where and " type query

Tags: redis

I'm new to Redis, I am now learning it by trying to make a login function.

Suppose I have a table named `User` *(id, username, password)* in traditional SQL database, what's the proper way to design the `Redis` store for a table, so that I may achieve some `sql-style-query` like `"select * from user where username=xxx and password=yyy"`?

Is it a good way to set the `key: username+password` and the `value: username "root" password "admin"` using `Hash`?

Comment: There's a huge difference between a key-value store like Redis and a relational database. You need to pick the right tool for the job. Please, do not **ever** store passwords as plain text, especially not in a key. This is completely reckless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redis is not a replacement for SQL databases. They have different purposes.
In Redis you should design based on how you will access the data.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535184/when-to-use-a-key-value-store-such-as-redis-instead-along-side-of-a-sql-database) SO question.

Also [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20120118030804/http://simonwillison.net/static/2010/redis-tutorial/) tutorial by Simon Willison is very interesting even though it has some years.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your query doesn't actually need to be `select * from user where username=xxx and password=yyy`, but instead just looking up by username and then verifying the password is correct.

Using Redis you can store the user information by the username (this is your primary/unique key) and then in your code verify the password is correct.  As @tadman has stated in the comments - please don't store passwords as plain text, that's a huge security hole right there