# Improve code: Displaying datetime of url when clicked in middleware

Tags: python, django, url, django-models

I have written a middleware and I would like some suggestions on how I could improve my code. I have a model that saves the date and the url when a new instance of it is created (in a middleware, so everytime a url is visited).

Like so:

Middelware:

```
class GetUrlMiddleware():
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        # before view

     urltime = UrlTime.objects.create(associated_url=request.path)
     urltime.save()

        response = self.get_response(request)
        # after view

        return response
```

Model:

```
class UrlTime(models.Model):
    url_track_model = models.ForeignKey(UrlTrack, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    associated_url = models.CharField(blank=True, null= True, max_length=250)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField('Url viewed on: ',default=datetime.now, blank=True)
```

Now, everytime I click a link, a new object is created with the url and the date. That all works fine.

I have the feeling this could be done better. Is there for instance a way in which I could add a column every time I click the link with the url? Or maybe some other better way?

Help is of course very much appreciated Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you need to save it?

Comment: thanks for the hint! But yep, I do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [redis](https://pypi.org/project/redis/) instead of an actual model for this and in conjunction with the `HSET` and `HGET` commands you could do the following:

```
from datetime import datetime

current_hits = redis_client.hget("links_hits", request.path) or []
current_hits.append(datetime.now())
redis_client.hset("links_hits", request.path, current_hits)
```

Comment: I have to admit I never worked with redis, but I will mos def check that out. Thanks so much my friend! Would you say that in regards to performance and high traffic that redis would be a more lightweight solution?

Comment: @Micromegas since it's a in-memory "database" the reads and writes are way faster than using a classical RDBMS. More info on the subject can be explored in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7537951/858565)